# Python - Pandas Output Limits Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, io

When dealing with Pandas, I'm attempting to print analysis of an objects Kinematic and Angular states. My code for doing so is as follows:

```
def displayData(tList, xList, zList, dxList, dzList, thetaList, dthetaList, Q_sList):
    states = pd.DataFrame({ 't' : tList,
                            'x' : xList,
                            'z' : zList,
                            'dx' : dxList,
                            'dz' : dzList,
                            'theta' : thetaList,
                            'dtheta' : dthetaList,
                            'Q_s' : Q_sList})

    print states[['t', 'x', 'z', 'dx', 'dz', 'theta', 'dtheta', 'Q_s']]
```

However, when asked to print the data, the output breaks up the columns beyond a certain point:

```
          t           x           z          dx         dz     theta  \
0     0.000 -500.000000 -100.000000  100.000000  -0.000000  0.000000   
1     0.005 -499.500000 -100.000000   99.999983   0.057692 -0.000577   
2     0.010 -499.000000  -99.999712   99.999933   0.115329 -0.001153
...     ...         ...         ...         ...        ...       ... 

        dtheta       Q_s  
0    -0.115385 -0.038462  
1    -0.115274 -0.038425  
2    -0.115163 -0.038388
...        ...       ...
```

As I have many thousands of states to print at the time, I would like for pandas to not break the table up like so, allowing me to analyze one given state without having to scroll to pick up the remaining two data fields. Is there any way I can define specific dimensions to be printed out so that this does not occur?

Comment: set: `pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr = False`

Comment: Shouldn't that be an answer? This question appears unanswered from the outside world. The fact that it's a small answer shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: @vmg, i have added an answer with a small demo - i think it can be useful  for those, having the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two useful [settings](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html) which can be used in this case: `pd.options.display.width` and `pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr`

Here is a small demo:

```
In [118]: pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr
Out[118]: True

In [119]: pd.options.display.width = 50

In [120]: df
Out[120]:
       t      x           z          dx  \
0  0.000 -500.0 -100.000000  100.000000
1  0.005 -499.5 -100.000000   99.999983
2  0.010 -499.0  -99.999712   99.999933

         dz     theta    dtheta       Q_s
0 -0.000000  0.000000 -0.115385 -0.038462
1  0.057692 -0.000577 -0.115274 -0.038425
2  0.115329 -0.001153 -0.115163 -0.038388

In [121]: pd.options.display.width = 100

In [122]: df
Out[122]:
       t      x           z          dx        dz     theta    dtheta       Q_s
0  0.000 -500.0 -100.000000  100.000000 -0.000000  0.000000 -0.115385 -0.038462
1  0.005 -499.5 -100.000000   99.999983  0.057692 -0.000577 -0.115274 -0.038425
2  0.010 -499.0  -99.999712   99.999933  0.115329 -0.001153 -0.115163 -0.038388

In [131]: pd.options.display.width = 40

In [132]: df
Out[132]:
       t      x           z  \
0  0.000 -500.0 -100.000000
1  0.005 -499.5 -100.000000
2  0.010 -499.0  -99.999712

           dx        dz     theta  \
0  100.000000 -0.000000  0.000000
1   99.999983  0.057692 -0.000577
2   99.999933  0.115329 -0.001153

     dtheta       Q_s
0 -0.115385 -0.038462
1 -0.115274 -0.038425
2 -0.115163 -0.038388


In [125]: pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr = False

In [126]: df
Out[126]:
       t      x           z          dx        dz     theta    dtheta       Q_s
0  0.000 -500.0 -100.000000  100.000000 -0.000000  0.000000 -0.115385 -0.038462
1  0.005 -499.5 -100.000000   99.999983  0.057692 -0.000577 -0.115274 -0.038425
2  0.010 -499.0  -99.999712   99.999933  0.115329 -0.001153 -0.115163 -0.038388

In [127]: pd.options.display.width
Out[127]: 30
```

alternatively, you can use [set_options()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html) method

Here is a list of all `diplay` options:

```
In [128]: pd.options.display.
pd.options.display.chop_threshold     pd.options.display.latex              pd.options.display.mpl_style
pd.options.display.colheader_justify  pd.options.display.line_width         pd.options.display.multi_sparse
pd.options.display.column_space       pd.options.display.max_categories     pd.options.display.notebook_repr_html
pd.options.display.date_dayfirst      pd.options.display.max_columns        pd.options.display.pprint_nest_depth
pd.options.display.date_yearfirst     pd.options.display.max_colwidth       pd.options.display.precision
pd.options.display.encoding           pd.options.display.max_info_columns   pd.options.display.show_dimensions
pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr  pd.options.display.max_info_rows      pd.options.display.unicode
pd.options.display.float_format       pd.options.display.max_rows           pd.options.display.width
pd.options.display.height             pd.options.display.max_seq_items
pd.options.display.large_repr         pd.options.display.memory_usage
```